# No control interface appears on iOS app using MPRemoteCommandCenter

Tags: ios, swift, mpremotecommandcenter

In my iOS app, I play music and I want to display playback controls on the lock screen, allowing the user to control the audio player.

So following [this tutorial](https://nowplayingapps.com/how-to-give-more-control-to-your-users-using-mpnowplayinginfocenter/) and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@g4gurpreetoberoi/controlling-music-from-lock-screen-mpnowplayinginfocenter-3f75ec7972d6), here is what I tried with `MPRemoteCommandCenter`:

```
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge]) { [self] (granted, error) in
            if (granted)
            {
                self.initNotification(application)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Notifications permission denied because: \(error?.localizedDescription).")
            }
        }

        // ...

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    private func initNotification(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
        application.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().playCommand.isEnabled = true
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().playCommand.addTarget { event in
            return .success
        }
        
        var nowPlayingInfo = [String: Any]()
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "Movie Title"
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = "Artist Name"
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
```

It compiles and run, but for some reason, nothing appears on the lock screen or in the notification center.

What did I forget?

Thanks.

Comment: What "notification" were you expecting? The remote command center has nothing to do with any "notifications" so what is about?

Comment: @matt I expect to see this: https://i0.wp.com/nowplayingapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/NowPlayingInfo-Lockscreen-7Plus.png?resize=504%2C1024&ssl=1, as explained in the tutorial I mentioned

Comment: Well, that's not a "notification". It's the remote control interface. It has nothing at all to do with  UNUserNotificationCenter. And it isn't something you'd just see. You'd need to go to that interface, yourself, at a time when your app is playing music.

Comment: All right then, I'm just used to Android where the equivalent of that control interface is a notification, so that's why I called it that way. Anyway, could you help me on that?

Comment: You're the one with the tutorial. You're evidently not doing what it says to do.

Comment: @matt ok but what did I miss then? I read the tutorial many times and still can't find my error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to read the tutorial for you. I already know how to make the remote command center work, and I've explained it elsewhere, and I've posted example code (for example [here](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/d4c84b61b9634f206cb1a5df73a8c16b6200820d/iOS14bookExamples/bk2ch14p644remote/ch27p912ducking/ViewController.swift)). I'm just explaining why your code is off the wall; you seem to imagine that there is some sort of connection with UNUserNotificationCenter, and there isn't — and I don't believe the tutorial told you there was.

Comment: Also please note that there are a _lot_ requirements in order for the remote command center to operate, and you have not demonstrated that you are meeting all of them.